Vue js 3 suspense not working with vuetify tabs
I am beginner in Vue js and I have stucked at issue with suspense with vuetify tabs. I have this structure of components:
App.vue
 |--- <ContactForm>
    |--- tabs        //simple 2 vuetify tabs
    |--- <basicData> //another component, so far it has just one api call (delayed) for mocking rest. Don't focus what is returning. It is just example.
    |--- <btn>       //simple button as a component because of reuse

I have created codesandbox for better understanding: Codesandbox
Issue
When Tab 1 is showed, first is rendered <btn/> component. After is rendered <basicData> component. What I want to achieve is to use <suspense> to show <basicData> and <btn/> at once. I don't want to put  inside , because of code duplication.
What I have tried so far

I have had <suspense> in <ContactForm> in various places - no effect
I put <btn/> component inside <basicData>, but this approach is working, but I don't want to copy code and put <btn/> in each tab component. Due to I want to use <btn/> for each tab, but not inside tab component.
I have tried use:

    <Suspense>
      <main>
        <v-tabs v-model="tab">
          <v-tab value="1">Tab 1</v-tab>
          <v-tab valu="2">Tab 2</v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
        <v-window v-model="tab">
          <v-window-item value="1">
            <basicData></basicData>
            <btn />
          </v-window-item>
          <v-window-item value="2">
            <otherData></otherData>
          </v-window-item>
        </v-window>
      </main>
      <template #fallback> Loading... </template>
    </Suspense>

Based on Vue documentation, each component has <script setup>.
I am out of idea, how to solve it. Thank you for any help or direction.
Update & solution
Well, solution was quite simple. I had code in tabs like this:
<v-window-item value="1">
  <basicData></basicData>
  <btn/>
</v-window-item>

but it just need to put <btn/> inside <basicData> component. (What a stupid mistake.). Like this:
<v-window-item value="1">
 <basicData>
  <btn/>
 </basicData>
</v-window-item>

Now it is working as expacted.
